# Append/merge List elements and assing ID column

Tags: r, list

I have a list of several element with different number of values.  I wish to merge all a to single column and b to another column. Further more I would like to assign new column with ID (where first a and first b gets id1, second a and second b gets id2...etc)

Here is an example of a list:

```
    # Reproducible problem
problem <- list(as.numeric(c(1:4)), as.numeric(c(25:28)), as.numeric(c(5:6)), as.numeric(c(29:30)), as.numeric(c(7:12)), as.numeric(c(31:36)))
names(problem) <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b")
```

And the result I'm expecting:

```
# Expected result
result <- list(as.numeric(c(1:12)), as.numeric(c(25:36)), c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id3", "id3", "id3", "id3", "id3", "id3" ))
names(result) <- c("a", "b", "id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'a', 'b', alternates and have the same 'length' for each pair, get the `lengths`, filter only the first element using the recycling of logical vector (`c(TRUE, FALSE)`).  Convert the initial `list` to a `data.frame` with `stack`, `split` the 'values' with 'ind' and `append` (or `c`) the 'id' `vector` created using 'i1'.

```
i1 <- lengths(problem)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
c(with(stack(problem), split(values, ind)), id = list(rep(paste0("id", 1:3), i1)))
#$a
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

#$b
#[1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

#$id
#[1] "id1" "id1" "id1" "id1" "id2" "id2" "id3" "id3" "id3" "id3" "id3" "id3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop assuming same length in a and b

```
result <- list(a = c(), b = c(), id = c())
i <- 1
for (j in seq(1, length(problem), 2)) {
  result[[1]] <- c(result[[1]], problem[[j]])
  result[[2]] <- c(result[[2]], problem[[j + 1]])
  result[[3]] <- c(result[[3]], rep(paste0('id', i), length(problem[[j]])))
  i <- i + 1                 
}
```